# I need to use apache httpd as a sort of proxy or filter, what's the best way?

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, httpd

I have server A (Jboss) which needs to get to server B (Tomcat), but I was told to proxy it through Apache HTTPD. I don't think that I want to truly set it up as a proxy server and set the proxy settings on JBoss, what I really need to do is have any request going to a certain port and/or URL pattern go be forwarded through to the Tomcat server.  How would I best do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

eg

```
 RewriteEngine  on
 RewriteRule    ^/(.*)$   http://SERVERB/$1
```